# Some links not visually highlighted on mobile

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web, markdown-rendering

In the mobile version, certain links appear in the same way as regular text, but they still can be selected as a link.

Take the first paragraph of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14096747/772868). In full-site rendering, the link for "failure-slice" is highlighted like this:

[image: good rendering]

But when you now select the mobile version the highlighting for "failure-slice" vanishes completely. Still, the link is there.

[image: bad rendering]

Comment: Why only half circles?? ;)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167823/can-the-color-of-visited-links-be-changed-on-the-mobile-site

Comment: That's because you clicked the link