# Can the color of visited links be changed on the mobile site?

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, markdown, mobile-web

When browsing the mobile [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) site links are displayed in a reddish tone. This is a good contrast to the text color. But whenever a link was visited it gets the very same color as the "normal" text. So if you visit a link, than go back to the question you won't see it anymore and it's like: "*Argh, which part was the link?*". Could this be changed?

In the image you see that effect on the "*edit*", "*delete*" and "*flag*" links, where it doesn't cause any trouble. The link within the paragraph "*[jQuery-Docs: '.animate()'](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)*" on the other hand is not this easy to notice anymore:

[image]

Comment: Low battery, so early in the morning? What *do* you do with your phone? =D

Comment: @J.Steen, some of us normally get up before 5:00, so I see no problem with his battery usage.

Comment: @Grammer Even as much as 4 hours to deplete an iPhone (even if it's got iOS 6.1) is a little short. Humour! =)

Comment: @J.Steen I got no good answer. :) But back in the day with my almost new iPhone 3GS and runnning iOS5 I had it down to 10% battery once after *4h, 8min standby* and *3h, 39min usage*. :)

Comment: @insertusernamehere Nice!

Comment: Maybe add [bug] to the tags. It *is* a bug, in the sense of a malfunction in how the web is supposed to work, even if someone somehow decided this was a good idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is fixed now.

Sorry about that -- I had created a typo in our mobile CSS:

```
.message a, a:visited
```

should have been

```
.message a, .message a:visited
```

Comment: It's nice to see that red tag [meta-tag:status-completed]. :) Thank you very much for your effort.